# jQuery $.ajax not working for a certain URL

Tags: ajax

`$.ajax` does not work when I use the following code:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<button>click</button>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: 'http://www.tuga-revolution.com/test.txt', success: function(result){
            $("#div1").html(result);
        }});
    });
});
</script>
```

But if I change the URL to another, for example this one:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js
```

then it works properly. It is possible that AJAX is blocked by the host?

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error in your console when you run it?

Comment: you could try to implement it from here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

The jquery.min.js file response contains an access-control-allow-origin header and thus it is allowed to be processed by AJAX

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
```

The test.txt file does not come with this header, and hence, it is blocked by the browser before the Javascript code can touch it.