# Ajax only working with certain urls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following code in JavaScript- #test is a simple h3 tag in html. I test that this can be changed with "test1". My question is why ajax will only work with certain URLs. In the following snippet, the success is never reached: in other words, #test does not become "test2". However, if I replace the URL with

'http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1'

success IS reached. Both link to JSON, and they look the same to me... so why is success only reached for the URL shown above?

A similar question-- [jQuery $.ajax not working for a certain URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310234/jquery-ajax-not-working-for-a-certain-url) --says that this is due to the same origin policy. Does this apply to my case as well? Is there any way to get around this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#test").html("test1");

    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=Albert%20Einstein&format=json',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#test').html("test2");

      },
      cache: false
    });
  });
})
```

Comment: It's probably the same problem. What does it say in your console log?

Comment: also, check the network tab of your developer console. It should provide a response if the request was successfully fired.

Comment: I use CodePen, and it says nothing

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around using jsonp as the data type, found here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Ajax#Limitations

My updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#test").html($("input").val());
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Boston%20Tea%20Party&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json",
      data: {
        format: 'json' 
      }, 
      dataType: 'jsonp',

      success: function(data) {
        $('#test').html(Object.keys(data.query.pages)[0]);
      },
      cache: false
    });
  });
})
```